# codeigniter - database : how to update multiple tables with a single update query

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I saw [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/141318/#695303) on the codeigniter forum

Considering the below code

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN b USING (id)
SET a.firstname='Pekka', a.lastname='Kuronen',
b.companyname='Suomi Oy',b.companyaddress='Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi'
WHERE a.id=1;
```

This is how you would apparently do it in Codeigniter

```
$this->db->set('a.firstname', 'Pekka');
$this->db->set('a.lastname', 'Kuronen');
$this->db->set('b.companyname', 'Suomi Oy');
$this->db->set('b.companyaddress', 'Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi');
$this->db->where('a.id', 1);
$this->db->join('table2 as b', 'a.id = b.id');
$this->db->update('table as a');
```

this does not work in reality. I have had a look a the SQL which this produces and the results do not even mention the join.

**Does anyone have any idea how to do an update with a join using Codeigniter's Active Record Database Class?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution I have found is to remove the join altogether and move the join condition into a 'where' function, also you will need to change the update string to include the new table.

```
$this->db->set('a.firstname', 'Pekka');
$this->db->set('a.lastname', 'Kuronen');
$this->db->set('b.companyname', 'Suomi Oy');
$this->db->set('b.companyaddress', 'Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi');

$this->db->where('a.id', 1);
$this->db->where('a.id = b.id');
$this->db->update('table as a, table2 as b');
```

Comment: I thought I would save someone some time. You need to use the "table as a" otherwise CodeIgniter tries to escape the tables and it fails.

Answer (score 4):

Using two separate queries within a [transaction](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) should solve your problem. If a query fails the other one gets rolled back.