# Is it possible to UPDATE a JOINed table using Codeigniter's Active Record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

Here is what I'd like to do

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $user_id)
{
    $this->db->where('post.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('post.post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->join('data', 'post.data_id_fk = data.data_id', 'left');
    $this->db->update('post', $data);
}
```

The 'post' table needs to be left-joined with 'data'.

When I run the above I get a SQL error saying that one of the fields from the 'data' table is not found.

Any suggestions?

MORE INFO

This is the generated SQL query

```
UPDATE `post` 
SET `data_value` = '111', `data_date` = '2012-02-13', `post_text` = '111' 
WHERE `post_stream_id` =  '5' 
    AND `post_id` =  '18'
```

This is the error

```
Unknown column 'data_value' in 'field list'
```

It doesn't show the JOIN statement.

Comment: What's the exact error message? Does the column exist?  What's the exact SQL it runs?

Comment: aaron, the column exists - just posted more code - Let me know what you think

Comment: reasonable solution here -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/4830380/445142

Answer (score 3):

Try this active record query for update with joins:

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $user_id)
{
    $this->db->set($data)
    $this->db->where('post.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('post.post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->where('post.data_id_fk = data.data_id');
    $this->db->update('post, data');
}
```

Comment: My solution is same as link you provided. So, please accept this answer. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for how accepting an answer work. Thank you!

Comment: I could not get your update line to work. It needed the "as" SQL syntax to get past CodeIgniter's escaping features.