# Active records class in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Basicly i have two tables photos and users. I wanna join tables and Update colums image_max and image_min. I get error unknown colum username. In which way i can join two tabels and get data from both. My sintax is:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('photos');
$this->db->join('users', 'photos.id = users.id');
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->update('photos',$data);
```

And I get error

> Unknown column `username` in `where` clause

```
UPDATE `photos` SET `image_max` = '', `image_min` = '' WHERE `username` = 'wwww'
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently you need a letter on the table should say "users.username", check that. 
Greetings.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('photos');
$this->db->join('users', 'photos.id = users.id');
$this->db->where('users.username',$username);
$this->db->update('photos',$data);
```

Comment: You can't do `join` and `where` without `set` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930184/codeigniter-this-db-join-used-with-this-db-update

Comment: you can put the table structure? to find the error?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "select and from" before upload fields, just update in this way

```
$data = array('image_max'=> 4, 'image_min' => 1);
$this->db->join('users', 'photos.id = users.id');
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->update('photos',$data);
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?