# codeigniter multiple table update query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

Here is my code

```
$RestaurantId=14;
$data['status']=0;

$this->db->set('a.status', $data['status']);
$this->db->set('b.status', $data['status']);
$this->db->where('a.id', $RestaurantId);
$this->db->join('b','a.id = b.business_location_id');
$result =$this->db->update('b_locations_info as a,b_images as b');
```

error:

Table `kpbaiger.b_locations_info as a,b_images` doesn't exist
On the SQL:

> UPDATE `b_locations_info as a,b_images` as `b` SET `a`.`status` = '0', `b`.`status` = '0'
>   WHERE `a`.`id` = '14'

Comment: help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830380/codeigniter-database-how-to-update-multiple-tables-with-a-single-update-quer

Comment: I've already tried that..But the same Issue

Comment: Please help me..Im still stuck