# codeigniter 3 update multiple tables with single query

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830380/codeigniter-database-how-to-update-multiple-tables-with-a-single-update-quer) to update multiple tables with single query, but this is not working in my case.

My query is as below:

```
$this->db->set('tbl1.col1', $val1);
$this->db->where('tbl1.col2', $val2);
$this->db->where('tbl1.col3', $val3);

$this->db->set('tbl2.col1', $val1);
$this->db->where('tbl2.col2', $val2);
$this->db->where('tbl2.col3', $val3);

$this->db->update('table1 as tbl1, table2 as tbl2');
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Table 'database.table1 as tbl1, table2' doesn't exist
```

This might not working in new version of codeigniter.

I am using `CI-3.1.6` and `PHP-5.6.12`

Is there any other way to update multiple tables with single query in codeigniter3?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check with **foreign keys** of this two tables.
For e.g.:

```
$this->db->where('tbl1.id = tbl2.id');
```

Here, `id` should be worked as **foreign key** of each other table.

Comment: using your code I am still receiving the same issue. It is merging two tables as one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating single column then use of `$this->db->where()` 2 times for particular table has no mean so its better to use it only 1 time .if you use foreign key to relate 2 table then update both table simultanously`$this->db->where('a.id', 1);
$this->db->where('a.id = b.id');`.hope this gonna work

Answer (score 0):

since you have to use `last_insert_id()` you have to use **two queries**, in the case of updating them is possible because the id already exists in the tables.